# Powershell disk monitoring

Tags: regex, powershell, monitoring

I have created the following script that returns the percentage of free space , the total space etc. of every disk for the remote servers the problem is that i want an extra column "warning" that prints No or Yes if the free space is bellow 10% i tried if statement but with no success. Please for your help.

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -filter "DriveType=3" -computer (Get-Content .\servers.txt) | Select SystemName,DeviceID,VolumeName,@{Name="Size(GB)";
Expression={"{0:N1}" -f($_.size/1gb)}},@{Name="FreeSpace(GB)";
Expression={"{0:N1}" -f($_.freespace/1gb)}},@{Name=" % Free(GB)";
Expression={"{0:N1}" -f(($_.freespace/$_.size)*100 )}},@{Name=" Warning";
Expression={????????}}  |Format-Table -AutoSize |Out-File disk_monitor.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like

```
@{Name="Warning";Expression={ if((100 / $_.Size * $_.FreeSpace) -lt 10) { "Yes" } else { "No" }} };
```

This will calculate what percentage of disk space is available *(100 / Size * FreeSpace)* and if it's less than 10 (as in, percent), will return *"Yes"* or otherwise *"No"*.

Comment: Thank you so much i have been trying hours for that! Thanks!!

Comment: I'm glad to hear it helped :)